# Wordpress - set custom field image to featured image for all posts

Tags: wordpress, image, thumbnails, custom-post-type, custom-fields

I need to set an image custom field 'blog_image' as a featured image for all my custom posts(`blog`). There are too many posts, and it is hard to it manually. I have searched google for 2 days long, but I didn't find the right solution.

Here is my code from `functions.php`

```
// get all posts from blog
$query = new WP_Query(
    array(
    'post_type' => 'blog',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    )
);
$all_posts = $query->posts;
foreach ($all_posts as $one_post)
{
    $value = get_field('blog_image', $one_post->ID);

    if ($value != '')
    {
     $thumbnail_id = $value->id;
     update_post_meta($one_post->ID, '_thumbnail_id', $thumbnail_id);
    }
}
```

I have var_dumped and print_r all my data, and I think everything should work, but it didn't.
Where I'm going wrong?

Comment: is `$one_post->ID` returning post_id ?

Comment: yes, it returns ids of all posts

Comment: Is this wrapped in a function? When is it called? Has it been hooked?

Comment: Also would it not be easier to change the single.php template if you just want the custom field 'blog_image' to replace the featured image? Or maybe I'm not understanding you correctly.

Comment: Try this: `update_post_meta( (int) $one_post->ID, '_thumbnail_id', (string) $value );` and `$value` returning `$thumbnail_id`?

Comment: Raunak Gupta i didn't understand you clearly, can you explain more detail?

Comment: I think this would need to be wrapped in a function and hooked into an action (not sure which one but you could try init)

Comment: @LEX: are you sure that `$value` has any value, how can you concluded that `update_post_meta` is not updating the DB?

Comment: Paul firstable i have tried this way, but it not wokrs

Comment: Raunak Gupta i var_dumped it, it returns an array of all images of all posts

Comment: that is wrong you have to save only ID of the thumbnail.

Comment: Raunak Gupta it returns only images from custom field 'blog_image' and all sizes of it

Comment: pls update your question with  the output of the `var_dump($value)`.

Comment: Raunak Gupta I have attached a screenshot of it

Comment: Thank you all guys, i found the solution after 2 days research, special thanks to Raunak Gupta :) The problem was in $thumbnail_id = $value->id; needs to be $thumbnail_id = $value['id'];

Answer (score 0):

> You should only save the thumbnail ID/image ID in `_thumbnail_id`;
>   which you want to set as featured image for `blog` post_type post.
>   WordPress use this ID to show featured image.

As you said that `blog_image` field return an array, so you have to extract the thumbnail ID form that array and then store it into `_thumbnail_id` post_meta.

You code 'll look like some thing like this:

```
//...
//...
foreach ($all_posts as $one_post)
{
    $value = get_field('blog_image', $one_post->ID); //it return an array with all the image data

    if ($value != '')
    {
//      echo '<pre>';
//      print_r($value);
//      echo '</pre>';
        //extracting the thumbnail ID from an array
        $thumbnail_id = $value->ID;
        update_post_meta($one_post->ID, '_thumbnail_id', $thumbnail_id);
    }
}
```

Please Note: *if you get an error or `$thumbnail_id` does not return the ID then uncomment `print_r` and see how to get that.*

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please update your question with the output of `echo '<pre>'; print_r($value); echo '</pre>';` and also let me a simple mapping example. like post_id: 2 should have an image name ::abc.jpg and image ID is 81.

Comment: did it, i just copied only first post dump, because there are many of them )))

Comment: thanks a lot  Raunak Gupta i found the solution! Need to be $value['id'] instead $value->ID